# Git Clean Branches

Tags: git, github, branch

I don't code professionally so forgive my ignorance.

A lot of repos I see only have two branches on github, master and maybe a previous branch. How do these repos keep such a clean repo after pull requests? When  people create branches to fix issues, do they push the new branch, create a pull request and then immediately delete the branch used in the pull? With forks it might be cleaner, but I've always done branches and wondering if there are better ways to keep things tidy.

Comment: Once a pull request is merged, GitHub tells you it's now safe to delete the branch and even provides a button to do so in the remote repo. See the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/deleting-and-restoring-branches-in-a-pull-request) for details.

Comment: Also most people do not have permissions on the repo, so they will create a fork, which creates a new repo in their account. The PR will then "pull" the commits from a branch in the fork directly to the master branch of the original repo. So the original repo only ever had the master branch.

Comment: I create branches all the time, and then immediately delete them once the feature or fix is merged in. They have no value (to me, anyway) once the work is done. So on repos where I have push access, you'll only see branches for work in progress, besides the main and release branches.  And of course on repos where I need to use a fork, you would not see my feature branches at all, but even there I clean them up quickly.